# How do I dynamically size UICollectionViewCell's height based on content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

What's the process for doing this?

I've discovered `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` but I'm not sure what I do in that method.  Do I create a new `UICollectionViewCell`, add in my content, and then return the size of that cell?

Do I need AutoLayout turned on and constraints set?  I apologize if this has been answered already.  I've been scouring stackoverflow, but haven't quite found a solution that worked.

Comment: you should look at - (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority

Comment: Do I need to setup constraints for my cell to use this?  I'm getting `Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a size of zero for a collection view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard size instead.` and my cell is not showing up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to:

1. setup Auto Layout constraints on the cell's `contentView` that, taken all in all, bind the left edge to the right edge, and the top edge to the bottom edge. This is how the cell will express the size it wants to be.
2. *not* implement `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, since you will not be providing sizes on a per-cell basis.
3. set `estimatedItemSize` to some reasonably large value on your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object.

There is [a repo with an example](https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo).

Comment: I setup AutoLayout on my xib, setup my constraints on all my items, turned off `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and set `estimatedItemSize` to 400x500.  Yet, the layout is still showing the small default grid `UICollectionViewCell`s.

Comment: iOS 9 (filling in space to post)

Comment: Wait Nevermind I got it working.  I incorrectly set the estimatedItemSize.  Now its showing up!  :)  edit:  Do you have any more information on how this works?  When I rotate the screen my objects aren't spanning across the entire horizontal view.

Comment: to be honest I have found UITableView's automatic row sizing much more reliable than UICollectionView's self-sizing. I'm noticing that repo demo for 8.3 is broken in 9.0, and I can't see why. I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is in the beta.